# Using Parse as a backend for Layer users

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, layer

I'm using Parse as a backend for managing users for use in a messaging app, with the messaging service provided by Layer.

Layer defines an `ATLParticipant` protocol that user objects must conform to. This in turn specifies an `ATLAvatarItem` protocol for the display of the user avatar. One of the properties of the `ATLAvatarItem` protocol is `UIImage *avatarImage`.

As my users are Parse objects, the avatar image is stored on the user as a `PFFile`. Naturally, I want to retrieve the data to create an `UIImage` and fulfil the request for `avatarImage` in the background, so as not to block the main thread and lock the UI. However this means calling `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:`, which means that my call to `avatarImage` returns with `nil` as the block has not fired before the return.

Currently, I have the following code to check if the data is already downloaded before returning an UIImage, or downloading the data in the background in preparation for the next time the image is requested. This still gets the data on the main thread.

```
- (UIImage *)avatarImage {
    if(self.photo.isDataAvailable) {
        return [UIImage imageWithData:[self.photo getData]];
    }
    else {
        [self.photo getDataInBackground];
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way I can get the data from the PFFile and return an UIImage, without blocking the UI?